# Creating a file name in python with ‘YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.txt’ format

Tags: python, datetime

I have code that runs everyday and logs the output. whenever I execute the code want to create a file with "YYYY-MM-DD_HH-MM-SS.txt" dynamically? Is there a way I can create a file in such format?

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. it is possible. Also, it is pretty easy actually

Comment: Have a read over here - [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). Go over it and i'm sure you'll find what you're looking for

Comment: Using `datetime`: `format(datetime.datetime.now(),"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")+".txt"`.

Comment: Consider using an ISO standard format like `YYYY-MM-DDTHHMMSS.txt` instead. (The `T` between the day and the hour is literal.)

Comment: Both of the methods in the answers are using strftime. I suggest http://strftime.org/ for a reference to how that works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `datetime` library:

```
from datetime import datetime

file_name = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt')
with open(file_name, 'w') as fd:
    fd.write('write something')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
import time
filename = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S.txt')
```

Your question is not really detailed.